# Python utility to monitor website uptime (including resources)

Tags: python, monitoring

I'd like to have a utility running to periodically check our websites to make sure they're up and responding. Python is my preferred quick utility environment.

I know I can ping the server with `urllib2` or something, but I really want to test that all the resources are there and available as well (CSS, JS, images, etc). Something like what a browser does when it loads a page -- fetch the HTML, then fetch the resources required, and check for any 400 or 500 errors.

Is there some simple way to do this in Python? I could probably use regex to try to grab the resource URLs from the HTML, but I don't want to worry about whether I'm [doing it wrong](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Is there a tool or trick that will do the hard work, or will I have to parse the HTML myself? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What would you compare the results to? Would it have to crawl over your site recursively and anytime a resource is encountered, have it check if the resource came back as normal? I would think that could be time consuming when developing. Have you had an issue where various resources disappeared or is something else motivating that decision? I would think that hitting major pages and checking for a normal http response code would suffice. But that's just me.

Comment: @jlafay: I mainly want to make sure all CSS and JS links are valid. I'm not interested in parsing the contents of every resource, just confirming that everything is up and available. Sometimes resources get moved, renamed, Amazon S3 permissions aren't quite right... whatever. Obviously we do our best to check before a change goes live, but I'd like to know that all the pieces are there, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For availability monitoring I'd recommend a 3rd party service like [newrelic.com](http://newrelic.com/features/availability-monitoring) or [site24x7.com](http://www.site24x7.com/web-site-availability.html).

If you want to roll your own (which isn't so hard if you have only basic needs) just use an HTML parser and iterate over the DOM to request your linked resources. Just don't use regexes.

Comment: Tools to consider: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Comment: I ended up rolling my own, which was actually quite easy with BeautifulSoup -- about 40 LOC. Basically it just requests a webpage and then gets every `<a>`, `<img>`, `<script>`, and `<link>` URL (if any) and makes sure each HTTP request gets a 200 response code. Perfect for a quick sanity check!